# Problema ao rodar app android no delphi

Tags: android, delphi, sdk

Ao tentar executar um app em delphi:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 E:\Firemonkey-Mapview-master\Android\Release\JSONMaps\AndroidManifest.xml:39: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Versão do SDK: 24.0.2 32bits

o xml que aparentemente apresenta o problema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.JSONMaps"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="JSONMaps" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4323000" />

        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="JSONMaps"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="JSONMaps" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

*rodando em desktop ele funciona

Answer (score 1):

O erro diz que seu `AndroidManifest.xml` está mal formatado. De acordo com seu código, na linha 39 localiza-se o seguinte:

```
<%services%>
```

Esta *tag* ao que parece, foge da sintaxe do `.xml`. Tente verificar para que serve, se de fato tem que ser usado desta forma, ou até mesmo se faltou alguma barra, etc.

Para [mais detalhes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=pt-br), verifique a estrutura do arquivo *manifest* [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html).